# unitarily equivalent

Tags: operator-theory

Let $A$ be a type $II_1$ factor (separably acting) with non trivial fundamental group. Some papers underline that in this case the algebra $A$ is isomorphic to $M_k(A)$ for some integer $k\geq 2$ but i can't find the proof.

1. Is $A$ isomorphic to $M_k(A)$ or even better unitarily equivalent?
2. Does anyone know the proof or some paper which contains this proof?

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. By definition, $A\cong M_k(A)$ if and only if $k$ belongs to the fundamental group of $A$. But every countable subgroup of $\mathbb R_+$ occurs as fundamental group of a $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor [1], in particular groups of the form $\{\lambda^n\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}$ for transcendental $\lambda>0$. Clearly these groups do not contain any integer other than $1$.

[1] S. Popa, *Strong Rigidity of $\textrm{II}_1$ Factors Arising from Malleable Actions of w-Rigid Groups I*, Invent. Math.
165 (2006), 369–408.

Comment: Perfect. I found the paper you recommend.